# SQLite command with multiple conditions and varying update

Tags: python, sqlite

I am struggling with some SQL. I have three vectors

```
Col_1s     = ["bob","fred", "bruce"]
Col_2s     = ["smith","johnson","macdonald"]
Increments = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to update the entry in a column called score in a sqlite tabel where Col_1=Col_1s[i] AND Col_2 =Col_2s[i], by adding the value Increments[i]; for i=0,1 and 2.

My intuition was that this command would work:

```
c.executemany("UPDATE statements SET Score = Score + (?) WHERE Col_1=(?) AND Col_2 =(?)", (Increments, Col_1s, Col_2s,))
```

where c is my cursor, but i get:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 9 supplied.
```

EDIT:
I realised that I was forgetting how executemany works. Now I am doing this:

```
for i in range(0, len(Col_1s), 1):
        Params[i] = [increments[i], Col_1s[i], Col_2s[i]]

c.executemany("UPDATE statements SET Score = Score + (?) WHERE Col_1s=(?) AND Col_2s=(?)", Params)
```

Frustratingly it still doesn't work.

Comment: If your condition is `where Col_1=Col_1s[0] AND Col_2 =Col_2s[0]` why do you supply `Col_1s` and `Col_2s`?

Comment: Because i want to do it for all the entries of the vectors, I've edited the above to make it clearer!